# Lenovo A850 bricked while flashing stock ROM

Tags: unbricking, lenovo, flashtool

My phone Lenovo A850 (MT6582) bricked just now. I accidentally pulled out the USB cable when it was flashing stock ROM by using Smart Phone Flash Tool. Now it's not charging and won't turn on, like a dead phone. I can get into MTK Meta Mode by pressing <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> & <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> then connect the USB, with and without battery. But when I try to flash anything, it gives error 4032. Please help me this is not my phone and I broke it! It does nothing when I press power button.

Comment: Does it vibrate or display shows anything at least when you attempt to power it on?

Comment: Nothing happen when i press the power button ,

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct ROM for that variant of the phone you are trying to flash?, try changing varants if you are not sure because this problem mostly arises if the ROM isn't compatible with your phone, if you are sure of the model then I think the problem might be incompatible variants

Answer (score 0):

Is your PC showing preloader devices connected in devices and printer menu
when you put the USB cable in your device without battery (press volume key 3 or 4 time)?
If it is showing, then you can flash your stock ROM again.